# Issue when try to access Windows 7 folder from Ubuntu 14.04 PC

Tags: 14.04, networking, windows-7

**PC01 - Windows 7**

Below settings are ENABLED from 'advanced sharing settings'

- Turn on Network Discovery
- Turn on File and Printer sharing

**PC02 - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**

- Samba service is installed on this PC.
- Both computers have same group "WORKGROUP"

Initially when I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I was able to access Windows share folder without any additional services or settings. But then I had to reinstall Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, there after I am not able to access Windows 7 shared folders from Ubuntu PC.

I am not able to see Windows 7 PC when I click on Network feature in left panel of Ubuntu.

What settings / services are missing or what wrong I am doing? Please advise about this.

Thank you All,

Answer (score 1):

Try going to the **Connect to server** on the Left side panel of nautilus and type in the address bar:
**smb://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX**, 
Where **X is the IP address of your Windows 7 PC** on your **local network**. 
Works for Me. Don`t know why it happens though.

Also, you may want to change the settings from: let Windows manage to: use User accounts and passwords, in your sharing tab.